# gcloud cli failing to add record when contents start with dash

Tags: bash, gcloud, lets-encrypt

I'm working with the LetsEncrypt [dns-01 challenge system](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge) which entails dynamically creating a TXT record in Google Cloud DNS with specific content, so LE can assert proof of ownership for generating a wildcard certificate (so I can't use http-01). The problem is sometimes LE tells me to create a TXT record that starts with a "-", for example `-E_DFDFHJKF1783FSHDJ`. I cannot get the `gcloud` cli to properly accept this data no matter what I do.

Example:

```sh
gcloud dns record-sets transaction start --zone=myzone
gcloud dns record-sets transaction add "-E_ASDFSDF" --ttl=30 --zone=myzone --name=test --type=TXT
gcloud dns record-sets transaction remove "-A_DSFKHSDF" --ttl=30 --zone=myzone --name=test2 --type=TXT
```

If you run those commands and inspect the resulting `transaction.yaml` you can see whether it properly contains the right string. If it did it correct, you should see something like:

```
- kind: dns#resourceRecordSet
  name: test.
  rrdatas:
  - '"ASDFASDF"'
  ttl: 30
  type: TXT
```

I am executing this via Node's `child_process`, but I have the issue even if I execute it directly from bash, so Node isn't really meaningful issue at the moment. I've tried echoing the value in. I've tried setting an environment variable and using that in the string.

No matter what I do I get an error like the following:

`ERROR: (gcloud.dns.record-sets.transaction.add) unrecognized arguments: -E_ASDFSDF`

Comment: For a TXT resource record data, a hyphen is legal. However, the CLI interprets rrdata that starts with a hyphen as a command-line option. My suggestion is to either use the Google Cloud Console or abort Let's Encrypt and start over if it asks you to create rrdata that starts with a hyphen. The Google Cloud Console DNS server UI does allow rrdata that starts with a hyphen. Consider opening a bug report: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Issue created... I'll respond based on the result. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193054503 .

Answer (score 2):

It turns out some characters need to be escaped in the CLI. I can confirm that the following works:

```
gcloud dns --project=myprojectid record-sets transaction add "\-test123" --name=test.mydomain.com. --ttl=300 --type=TXT --zone=myzoneid
```